# How to get the start time and end time of method in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

I have a method in my controller upload method which converts the uploaded image file into three different sizes. I want to dispaly the time taken from when the file is uploaded and and the end of the method the conversion stopped can any one tell me how can I do this

```
       this is my controller


           public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        //ViewBag.ProcessingTime = DateTime.Now;
        return View();
    }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Uploading(ImageModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("time is"+System.DateTime.Now);

                string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd/hh/mm/ss/fff");
                string serverPath = Server.MapPath("~");
                string imagesPath = serverPath + "Content\\Images\\";
                string thumsise = Path.Combine(imagesPath, "Thumb" + fileName);
                string thumbPath = Path.Combine(imagesPath, "Thu" + fileName);
                //string thumbPath = imagesPath + "Thumb\\";
                string fullPath = Path.Combine(imagesPath, "Full" + fileName);
                //string fullPath = imagesPath + "Full\\";
               // string Bigpath = imagesPath + "big\\";
                string Bigpath = Path.Combine(imagesPath, "big" + fileName);
                string Bigpatha = Path.Combine(imagesPath, "biga" + fileName);
                string Bigpathb = Path.Combine(imagesPath, "bigb" + fileName);
                //string Bigpatha = imagesPath + "biga\\";
                //string Bigpathb = imagesPath + "bigb\\";
                string Bigpathc = Path.Combine(imagesPath, "bigc" + fileName );
                //string Bigpathc = imagesPath + "bigc\\";
                //var firstSize = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "bigsize-" + Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile));
                ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(thumsise, fileName, model.ImageUploaded.InputStream, 80, true);
                ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(thumbPath, fileName, model.ImageUploaded.InputStream, 100, true);
                ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(fullPath, fileName, model.ImageUploaded.InputStream, 500, true);
                ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(Bigpath, fileName, model.ImageUploaded.InputStream, 200, true);
                ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(Bigpatha, fileName, model.ImageUploaded.InputStream, 250, true);
                ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(Bigpathb, fileName, model.ImageUploaded.InputStream, 150, true);
                ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(Bigpathc, fileName, model.ImageUploaded.InputStream, 50, true);
                Console.WriteLine("Time is " + System.DateTime.Now);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Time is "+System.DateTime.Now);

            Console.ReadLine();
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add the additional fields in your `Model`:

```
 public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
 public DateTime OperatingTime { get; set; }
 public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
```

Then assign each appropriately, i.e. `StartTime = DateTime.Now;`

Then in your `View`:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.StartTime);
```

**Additional**

I would personally wrap the upload image functionality into a new method, preferably in your `ImageModel` class.  You could then do: `model.UploadImage(fileName, imagePath);`

Answer (score 0):

Use a stopwatch

```
   var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
   stopwatch.Start();    
   //whatever you want to time
   stopwatch.Stop();
   var result1 = string.Format("{0} to run whatever ", 
                               stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
   Console.WriteLine(result1);
```

for multiple timings then you can reset stopwatch and do more timings similar to the first one.

Comment: what do i have to do "{0} to run whatever " this place

Comment: {0} will be replaced by stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString().  i'll update to use your console if you like